# Django Sessions, SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE does not change session expire date

Tags: django, django-sessions

I have set

```
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
```

in my settings.py and it works fine.

The problem is that when the user closes the browser, he is logged out just fine but in the session instance related to that user the

```
expire_date
```

field does not change.

I have a piece of code for listing all active sessions.

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.utils import timezone

sessions = Session.objects.filter(expire_date__gte=timezone.now())
uid_list = []

for session in sessions:
    data = session.get_decoded()
    uid_list.append(data.get('_auth_user_id', None))
    print("#", uid_list[-1])
```

The output of the code contains the user id of the logged out user.

The Session Base Class is:

```
class AbstractBaseSession(models.Model):
session_key = models.CharField(_('session key'), max_length=40, primary_key=True)
session_data = models.TextField(_('session data'))
expire_date = models.DateTimeField(_('expire date'), db_index=True)

objects = BaseSessionManager()

class Meta:
    abstract = True
    verbose_name = _('session')
    verbose_name_plural = _('sessions')

def __str__(self):
    return self.session_key

@classmethod
def get_session_store_class(cls):
    raise NotImplementedError

def get_decoded(self):
    session_store_class = self.get_session_store_class()
    return session_store_class().decode(self.session_data)
```

The question is that how do I know if a user has closed the browser and logged out.

Answer (score 0):

That's by design, as there is no way the user closing their browser could signal anything to Django.

`SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE` just means that the cookie that the browser sends to Django expires when the browser is closed, and as such the next browsing session will not be associated with the same Django session.